# A function creating variable names for parameters that I never gave

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am learning JavaScript from an eloquent book and in the chapter about higher order functions I found this code:

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(...args) => {
    console.log("calling with", args);
    let result = f(...args);
    console.log("called with", args, "returned", result);
    return result;
  };
}

noisy(Math.min)(3,2,1);
// calling with [3,2,1]
// called with [3,2,1] returned 1
```

I know that the rest parameter `...args` takes a number of arguments and groups them into an array, but when did I gave any parameter to the arrow function?
Does `args` automatically contain all the extra parameters passed to `noisy()` (which is expecting only `f`)?
If yes what are the rules of this way of using parameters?
Could I have used even only the first two extra parameters?
Shouldn't the original code be like the following?

```
function noisy(f, ...args) {
    return function(args) => { // with the rest of the program
```

Comment: This example shows two aspects of higher order functions; being able to pass functions as arguments (passing `Math.min`) AND being able to return functions as results (returning the arrow function)

Comment: I need to get used to returned functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when did I gave any parameter to the arrow function

You passed them in the `(3,2,1)` part of `noisy(Math.min)(3,2,1)`. `noisy()` is returning a function which you are then calling immediately with parameters `(3,2,1)`

it might be clearer to break out that call

```js
var myArrowFunction = noisy(Math.min)
myArrowFunction(3,2,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I just noticed that (1,2,3) were not arguments of `noisy`, but anyway the most tricky part was aknowledge that `noisy` returns a function rather the returned value of the returned function.